# How can I set the origin of StretchDIBits to the top left corner?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using Win32Api, and I'm looking for a way to load BGR (or RGB, BGRA, RGBA...) data to a window.

is going from the bottom left and weaving its way up, like this paragraph.
gradually going downwards to end at the bottom right, StretchDIBits
Instead of starting from the top left, going to the top right, and

This is how I made winW and winH:

```
const unsigned int winW = 800;
const unsigned int winH = 600;
unsigned char buffer1[winW * winH * 3]; // desired window data array, one-dimensional
```

This (trimmed) is how I'm currently using the WindProc method:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hDC;
RECT client;
switch (message)
{
case WM_PAINT:
    hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &client);
    StretchDIBits(hDC,
        0, 0,
        client.right, client.bottom,
        0, 0,
        winW, winH,
        buffer1, &bitInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

If I try to flip it along the center horizontal line (swapping winH and its 0, or client.bottom and the second 0), all I get is a blank white screen.

I'm not particularly interested in scaling or resizing the window, so using a different function or method is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flip the bitmap vertically:

Start from `client.bottom` for Y coordinate. Then swap the sign for height to `-client.bottom`:

```
StretchDIBits(hDC,
    0, client.bottom,
    client.right, -client.bottom,
    0, 0,
    winW, winH,
    buffer1, &bitInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```